# Search through a list of computers to find a string in a file

Tags: powershell

Iam trying to find a string in the hosts files of computers in a text file. I want to check each machine. I want the result to a file (ex: found string on server1).

Below is the script, but I could not get the output I wanted.
Can someone help me on this?

```
$sys = Get-Content .\Systems.txt

$SearchStr = "string"

ForEach ($System in $sys) {

    $Loc = "\\$system\c`$\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
    if(Select-String -pattern $SearchStr -path $Loc -Quiet) {
        Write-Output "$system Found"
    } else {
        Write-Output "$system Not Found"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? Does the `Select-String` command work on these computers outside your script?

Comment: When I run the script, if the string is found in the server(ex: test1) which is listed in systems.txt, it will write to a text file saying "test1". But if it is not present, it is not dumping to the test file. I am looking to find a string in a file on a multiple servers and write to text file. Result should be as: If the string is found, it has to write - server name: found string. If the string is not found, it has to write string not found. These can be stored in two files, one is found string with server names and other file can be string not found with server names.

Comment: Your script is working on my system, what is blocking you exactly ? (you can edit your question to add details and or code)

Comment: Thanks all, its working. The script looks good, just added ">> File name" at end of write-output command. It started working.